# Array for Column Headers

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to store all of the column headers in an array that I can then use to populate a UserForm. This would allow the different headers to act as column selection for later code. However, I cannot seem to get the array to assign correctly

I have attempted different looping structures but continue to be met with "Subscript out of range" errors

```
Option Explicit

Sub Audit_Template_Autofill()

    Dim column_id() As Variant, A1 As Range, z As Range, c As Range
    Dim x As Long, column_count As Long

    Set A1 = Range("A1")

    Set z = A1.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)

    column_count = Range(A1, z).Count 

    x = 0
    For Each c In Range(A1, z)
         column_id(x) = c.Value
         x = x + 1
    Next c
End sub
```

I was originally testing the assignment by using

```
For each c in range(A1, z)
     debug.print = c.value
next c
```

which accurately printed all of my headers, I just cannot seem to assign them into the array correctly. I apologize for the code not being overly clean, this is more of a testing exercise to implement in a larger model. I have done this sort of loop before, but I cannot seem to recall how I wrote it.
Thanks!

Comment: Why not just read the range into a 2D array in one go, as demonstrated [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)? Or do you absolutely need a 1D array?

Comment: `column_id()` needs to be sized.  Look at `Redim`  As @BigBen says, the range will easily translate to an array

Comment: Thank you guys! I did ```ReDim column_id(0 to column_count)``` instead of x=0 and that seemed to cover it

Comment: Creating a ListObject (table) out of your data is a great way to be able to work with headers and the data rows separately.

Comment: Mathieu Guindon has a great example posted here:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/vozhez4wwdlfg8f/WorkbookProxyExampleDialog.xlsm?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

**Assign headers to Array**

The easiest way is to

- [1] create a (1-based) 2-dimensional array by assigning a range's value to `headers`
- [2] make it a **"flat"** 1-dim array (btw 1-based, too) via **double transposition**;
     (note that this isn't possible by `ReDim Preserve` which allows only to redimension the last (here: 2nd Dimension), but not to "remove" a Dimension).

BTW Your original code lacks of a `ReDim column_id(0 To …)` before starting the loop assignments to make it *"work"*; furthermore the variable `x` defaults to `0` automatically by declaring it. Suggest to fully qualify your range references, etc.

```
Sub Columns2Array()
Dim headers() As Variant
  ' [1] create a (1-based) 2-dimensional array by assigning a range's value to headers
    headers = Sheet1.Range("A1:" & Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Address)
  ' [2] make it a "flat" 1-dim array (btw 1-based, too) via double transposition
    headers = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(headers))

  ' a) test headers items by one code line
    Debug.Print Join(headers, ",")
  ' b) test headers via loop
    Dim colNo&
    For colNo = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        Debug.Print "headers(" & colNo & ") = ", headers(colNo)
    Next colNo
End Sub
```

Comment: Would appreciate your feed back if you found my approach helpful :-) @KN1GHTS